# Getting the most valuable path

Tags: c, matrix, multidimensional-array, path, checksum

[our table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C77NB.png)

[one of the best paths](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ve5be.png)

Giving the above matrix, what is in your opinion the best way to get the most valuable path and print it, but the movement that someone can do is down and right.

What i thought is that someone can check the right and above pos of the matrix and whichever is larger then get his position and move.

Comment: Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly don't forget how to create a [mcve] of your attempt and show it to us.

Comment: I think that my question is perfectly clear. I cannot give all my code here its like 300 hundred lines.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude is most likely not telling you to be more clear, but more likely stating that this sort of question is subjective and not what this forum is intended for.

Comment: Your question might be crystal clear, but it does not meet the standards accepted on StackOverflow. Few of the issues: 1) Links to images. 2) Asking for *opinion*. 3) No demonstrated effort.

Comment: I ask if my way of thinking is right then I will implement it give it here to check if its like good way of implementing this kind of problem